# Assigning new data point to cluster after pca

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca, dataset

I have a large dataset with a lot of features, I applied PCA on it and then run it through clustering algorithm.
I have another large dataset with the same features from different area and I want to check to which cluster each point fit sepreatly.
How I do it? Do I need to apply PCA to the new dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to process your new data in the same way that you processed the original data.  Regarding PCA, you will need to apply the weights from the original PCA to the new data, and *not* do a new PCA on the new data.  Using the original weights will ensure that all data, new and old, are comparable and have been treated similarly.

Regarding clustering, how to assign new data points to 'old' clusters (in respect to their locations, cutoffs, etc) depends on the type of clustering you did, but the same rule applies as for PCA - do your cluster assignment using the information (cluster locations, cutoffs, etc) obtained from clustering on the original data.

Comment: `how to assign to new clusters` You probably meant "how to assign new points to 'old' (in respect to their locatiions, cutoffs, etc) cluster". Right?

Comment: Good catch!  I've edited the response.